# Array will not find the element I am looking for

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know whats the error in my code. This question is asking me to create an array that stores random numbers between 1 and 300 inclusive, and asking me to find the element in the array (if it is present or not). I didn't see any error in the code so I assumed it is a logical error.

The error I got when i run the program is that there will not be an output in the CMD, instead my cpu usage will just increase and my laptop fan got louder as the program runs.

Any idea to what's the error? Thank you in advanced.

```
public class Array
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int [301];
        int input;
        boolean isPresent = false;
        int i = 0;
        int t = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt(300);
            arr[i] = randomNum;
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the element you want to find");
            input = sc.nextInt();
            if (input <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println ("Error, must be greater than 0");
            }
        }while (input <= 0);


        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == input)
            {
                isPresent = true;
                i = t;
            }

            else
            {
                isPresent = false;
            }
        }

        if (isPresent = true)
        {
            System.out.println("Element is found at position " + (t));
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very simple, you need to leave the loop once you have found something, and set `isPresent` to true,  using `break`. Otherwise you will mostly likely set `isPresent` to false after you have found something. In general it is better to assign a boolean an initial value and then have only once condition to check if it should be changed.

Comment: Don't get used to use `break` and `continue` in a loop. This is java, not assembly: rewrite the loop condition instead.

Comment: That's ridiculous, using `break` or `continue` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Sterconium there's plenty of cases in which `continue` and `break` are the correct solution. Especially in `for` loops putting the exit condition (in this case `arr[i] == input`) directly in the loop condition tends to be ugly.

Comment: My professor always said so because it makes the code harder to read, however [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices) is a discussion with other reasons.

Comment: @Sterconium your professor generalized something that should not be generalized

Comment: Actually I don't remember precisely what he said, however the linked discussion should talk for my point (They mention pros too, don't get me wrong).

Comment: @Sterconium (last message from me about this because we're veering off-topic) me and Joakim were taking issue with your statement to not get used to `break` and `continue` which was not qualified (i.e. when is it wrong?) and, in general, not always true. As you said, that link also gives reason where they make sense.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, not comparison. Also, you usually don't need to explicitly compare to `true` or `false`, and it's considered poor style to do so.

Comment: Using a `break` or `continue` inside a loop is for me a natural part of designing loops so that they are easier to understand but one good point that was made in the linked discussion is that if they are overused it is really bad since the logic gets hard to follow, same goes for `return` statements.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to `break` the loop when you find it's present:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == input) {
        isPresent = true;
        t = i; // instead of i = t
        break; // this is very important
    }
}
```

And then change your condition:

```
if (isPresent = true)
```

to:

```
if (isPresent)
```

Comment: Skip the `else` and initialise `isPerfect` to false instead. (Actually in the question it is already set to false so just skip the `else`)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I have updated the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0, t = 0;        
for (i=0; i<arr.length && t==0; i++){
    if (input == arr[i]){
        t = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(t>0?"Found at "+t:"Not found");
```

This solution stops as soon as `input` is found, tests `t` instead of using another boolean, and doesn't use `break`.